# How can I make `react-scripts build` quiet?

Tags: react-scripts

I am working with a repo with a number of Node packages created with `create-react-app`, all of which are built and tested by the CI system. Each package's build/test, done with `react-scripts build` followed by `react-scripts test --silent`, is currently producing over twenty lines of output resulting in a build log with well over a hundred lines of material such as "File sizes after gzip" and "Find out more about deployment here." This makes it more difficult to see error messages, warnings or other problems in that log.

Is there some way for me to quiet this down short of writing my own custom build script (and possibly test script, too) for each one of the packages? If I do need custom scripts, what's the best way to re-use as much as possible of the existing code that's doing the build and test?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this problem?

Comment: @LukasGjetting I investigated and at this time the only solution appears to be to use a different build script. See the answer I just posted below for details. And thanks for the PR to fix this.

Comment: you could create a batch file that executes the `react-scripts`. That allows you to make that batch file silent. e.g. on windows you would put `@echo off` on the first line of that batch file. Or alternatively redirect its output to a file with an `react-scripts build > file.txt`.

Comment: @bvdb The build is run by a shell script so it's already "silent" in the sense of `@echo off` in a `.BAT` file. The problem is the output coming not from the batch file but the build itself. And yes, I could redirect it, but then that would also redirect the error and warning messages hidden in all that verbose build output.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson I don't know how they implemented their output, but convention is that error messages are pushed to a seperate error output. i.e. `foo.exe 1> stdout.txt 2> errout.txt`. But I assume that you are right, that probably won't work. But in theory, you should be able to `react-scripts build 1> ignorestdout.txt` to only keep the error output.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson You are right about the `@echo off`, taking that back.

Comment: @bvdb It's not unusual for information about problems to be printed to stdout rather than stderr. (This happens for various reasons, such as the developer of the tool beliving that a warning isn't very important.) So I make it a policy always to capture both stderr and stdout, and examine both for anything that might indicate problems.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson then this may help you: `foo.exe | find /V "ignore this" | find /V "and ignore this"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`react-scripts build` runs `bin/react-scripts.js` from the `react-scripts` package which basically just runs `scripts/build.js` from that same package.

Sadly, that `build.js` script (as of 2018-10-15, anyway) is hard-coded to call functions such as `printFileSizesAfterBuild()` and `printHostingInstructions()`, without any option to disable these. So there's currently no way to change this except to make a copy of `build.js`, modify it not to print the things you don't want, and use that instead.

There is a pull request [PR #5429](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/5429) from @LukasGjetting to add a `--silent` option to the build script. It's been closed due to lack of inactivity, and the `create-react-app` developers have made it fairly clear in other places that they're not intending to make `react-scripts` very configurable; the solution they suggest is just to use your own `build.js` script.

Comment: This would require the project to be ejected right?

Comment: @paul23 You need to make your own copy of `build.js`; whether you chose to do that via an eject (which, IIRC, also copies a lot of other scripts) or not is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the build.js script from `/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js` in the root of your application, make the paths relative to a `const basepath = __dirname+'/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/'`
and elminate unnecessary logs.
Adjust the `package.json` scripts build to: `node build`
and you have a very quiet build for a react app :)

Sample build script:

```js
// @remove-on-eject-begin
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
// @remove-on-eject-end
'use strict';

// Do this as the first thing so that any code reading it knows the right env.
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'production';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
const basepath = __dirname + '/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/';
// Makes the script crash on unhandled rejections instead of silently
// ignoring them. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
// terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  throw err;
});

// Ensure environment variables are read.
require(basepath + '../config/env');
// @remove-on-eject-begin
// Do the preflight checks (only happens before eject).
const verifyPackageTree = require(basepath + 'utils/verifyPackageTree');
if (process.env.SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK !== 'true') {
  verifyPackageTree();
}
const verifyTypeScriptSetup = require(basepath + 'utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup');
verifyTypeScriptSetup();
// @remove-on-eject-end

const path = require('path');
const chalk = require('react-dev-utils/chalk');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const configFactory = require(basepath + '../config/webpack.config');
const paths = require(basepath + '../config/paths');
const checkRequiredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/checkRequiredFiles');
const formatWebpackMessages = require('react-dev-utils/formatWebpackMessages');
const printHostingInstructions = require('react-dev-utils/printHostingInstructions');
const FileSizeReporter = require('react-dev-utils/FileSizeReporter');
const printBuildError = require('react-dev-utils/printBuildError');

const measureFileSizesBeforeBuild =
  FileSizeReporter.measureFileSizesBeforeBuild;
const printFileSizesAfterBuild = FileSizeReporter.printFileSizesAfterBuild;
const useYarn = fs.existsSync(paths.yarnLockFile);

// These sizes are pretty large. We'll warn for bundles exceeding them.
const WARN_AFTER_BUNDLE_GZIP_SIZE = 512 * 1024;
const WARN_AFTER_CHUNK_GZIP_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;

const isInteractive = process.stdout.isTTY;

// Warn and crash if required files are missing
if (!checkRequiredFiles([paths.appHtml, paths.appIndexJs])) {
  process.exit(1);
}

// Generate configuration
const config = configFactory('production');

// We require that you explicitly set browsers and do not fall back to
// browserslist defaults.
const {
  checkBrowsers
} = require('react-dev-utils/browsersHelper');
checkBrowsers(paths.appPath, isInteractive)
  .then(() => {
    // First, read the current file sizes in build directory.
    // This lets us display how much they changed later.
    return measureFileSizesBeforeBuild(paths.appBuild);
  })
  .then(previousFileSizes => {
    // Remove all content but keep the directory so that
    // if you're in it, you don't end up in Trash
    fs.emptyDirSync(paths.appBuild);
    // Merge with the public folder
    copyPublicFolder();
    // Start the webpack build
    return build(previousFileSizes);
  })
  .then(
    ({
      stats,
      previousFileSizes,
      warnings
    }) => {
      // if (warnings.length) {
      //   console.log(chalk.yellow('Compiled with warnings.\n'));
      //   console.log(warnings.join('\n\n'));
      //   console.log(
      //     '\nSearch for the ' +
      //       chalk.underline(chalk.yellow('keywords')) +
      //       ' to learn more about each warning.'
      //   );
      //   console.log(
      //     'To ignore, add ' +
      //       chalk.cyan('// eslint-disable-next-line') +
      //       ' to the line before.\n'
      //   );
      // } else {
      //   console.log(chalk.green('Compiled successfully.\n'));
      // }
      //
      // console.log('File sizes after gzip:\n');
      // printFileSizesAfterBuild(
      //   stats,
      //   previousFileSizes,
      //   paths.appBuild,
      //   WARN_AFTER_BUNDLE_GZIP_SIZE,
      //   WARN_AFTER_CHUNK_GZIP_SIZE
      // );
      // console.log();
      console.log(chalk.green('Compiled successfully.\n'));

      const appPackage = require(paths.appPackageJson);
      const publicUrl = paths.publicUrlOrPath;
      const publicPath = config.output.publicPath;
      const buildFolder = path.relative(process.cwd(), paths.appBuild);
      // printHostingInstructions(
      //   appPackage,
      //   publicUrl,
      //   publicPath,
      //   buildFolder,
      //   useYarn
      // );
    },
    err => {
      const tscCompileOnError = process.env.TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR === 'true';
      if (tscCompileOnError) {
        console.log(
          chalk.yellow(
            'Compiled with the following type errors (you may want to check these before deploying your app):\n'
          )
        );
        printBuildError(err);
      } else {
        console.log(chalk.red('Failed to compile.\n'));
        printBuildError(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
    }
  )
  .catch(err => {
    if (err && err.message) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    process.exit(1);
  });

// Create the production build and print the deployment instructions.
function build(previousFileSizes) {
  // We used to support resolving modules according to `NODE_PATH`.
  // This now has been deprecated in favor of jsconfig/tsconfig.json
  // This lets you use absolute paths in imports inside large monorepos:
  if (process.env.NODE_PATH) {
    console.log(
      chalk.yellow(
        'Setting NODE_PATH to resolve modules absolutely has been deprecated in favor of setting baseUrl in jsconfig.json (or tsconfig.json if you are using TypeScript) and will be removed in a future major release of create-react-app.'
      )
    );
    console.log();
  }


  const compiler = webpack(config);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    compiler.run((err, stats) => {
      let messages;
      if (err) {
        if (!err.message) {
          return reject(err);
        }

        let errMessage = err.message;

        // Add additional information for postcss errors
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(err, 'postcssNode')) {
          errMessage +=
            '\nCompileError: Begins at CSS selector ' +
            err['postcssNode'].selector;
        }

        messages = formatWebpackMessages({
          errors: [errMessage],
          warnings: [],
        });
      } else {
        messages = formatWebpackMessages(
          stats.toJson({
            all: false,
            warnings: true,
            errors: true
          })
        );
      }
      if (messages.errors.length) {
        // Only keep the first error. Others are often indicative
        // of the same problem, but confuse the reader with noise.
        if (messages.errors.length > 1) {
          messages.errors.length = 1;
        }
        return reject(new Error(messages.errors.join('\n\n')));
      }
      if (
        process.env.CI &&
        (typeof process.env.CI !== 'string' ||
          process.env.CI.toLowerCase() !== 'false') &&
        messages.warnings.length
      ) {
        console.log(
          chalk.yellow(
            '\nTreating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.\n' +
            'Most CI servers set it automatically.\n'
          )
        );
        return reject(new Error(messages.warnings.join('\n\n')));
      }

      return resolve({
        stats,
        previousFileSizes,
        warnings: messages.warnings,
      });
    });
  });
}

function copyPublicFolder() {
  fs.copySync(paths.appPublic, paths.appBuild, {
    dereference: true,
    filter: file => file !== paths.appHtml,
  });
}
```

and  sample package.json script option:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start", "build": "node build"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, though I should point out that the question was focused around doing this _without_ having to extract and customize the build scripts. (It's not so bad doing so for one project, but doing and maintaining that for a dozen or so pojrects is rather more work.)

Comment: The changes are so straight forward that one could easily write a script to automatize the process: cope build script from path, inject that basepath, search for paths and change them, shell node new script, delete the script post factum.But, you are right :)

Comment: I think it's probably simpler and cheaper for long-term maintenance, if one's going to start writing more code, simply to create a new package based on the existing one with the preferred modifications. (Though in the end I believe we integrated the desired changes with our custom build system.)

Answer (score 0):

I spontaenously have [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) in mind. At least you can color code the responses. Sounds like the app you are working with is not (yet) ejected. Only when the app is ejected can you modify `create-react-app` base files. Unfortunately, once ejected you can not reverse the effects. Lmk if it helps

Comment: Part of the point was not to have to eject the app because then you need to manually copy in any script upgrades rather than just update a dependent `create-react-app` package.

Comment: Just pointed at the option. Now it's just a question of how badly you want it. Not worth it IMO. Sorry I couldn't be of more help

Comment: Well, thanks, but I was hoping it was already clear from "short of writing my own custom build script" that I wanted to use the standard script from the pakage.