# How to hide React start welcome message when using Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, docker-compose, yarnpkg

After building and starting a react app, we usually get a welcome message saying that we can access react at a particular url.

[image]

Is there a way to disable this? I set up a react app with docker-compose and this welcome message clears the screen and many important logs from other services.

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

EDIT:
It seems like many people are trying to solve the same question:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2495

A workaround would be great since facebook isn't even trying to address the problem as they've closed the ticket.

Comment: @Qiarash I'm not sure I understand your question. I build the docker container for the react app and I start it (which starts the application).

Comment: Can you put out the `package.json` file? Since it's related to what `yarn start` really run in your project

Comment: Basically, I want a workaround for this:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2495

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114824/how-can-i-make-react-scripts-build-quiet

Comment: It does. I'm very disappointed that there's no workaround.

Comment: Lol, at least we pinpointed the problem. Time for us to make a contribute

Answer (score 2):

If you avoid the more developer-oriented tooling in your Docker setup then you won't get the more developer-oriented messages.  For a browser-based application, you can compile it into static files and then serve it with your choice of Web server.

```sh
FROM node:12 AS build
WORKDIR /app
...
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:1.17
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
# Use base image's default EXPOSE, CMD, etc.
```

This won't support live reloading, but there are a number of prominent issues around that with Docker anyways, and you can run `yarn start` on your host targeting a Docker backend.  [Add a `"proxy"` setting to your `package.json` file](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development) pointing at the Docker-hosted backend; then `yarn start` will proxy API requests there for local development, but `yarn build` won't for the Docker-based deployment.

Comment: Great answer. I do use `yarn build` and `COPY --from` for production images, but I want to support live reloading for both client and server code in my docker-compose setup for faster iterating.