# React's webpack is showing up in the console

Tags: reactjs, webpack

i have a this little issue.
I have a new laptop, and I decided to do react project.
I installed the Node's stable version, installed the the npm create-react-app globally, and created a new project using this command `npx create-react-app tip-calculator`.

Everything was set up for me, only deleted a few files on the src folder, and kept the essentials (index.js, app.js and index.css).

My issues, is on my previous laptop, when doing projects, the webpack (is what i think it is) didn't show up in the console, and on the new laptop, it shows, and I would like it removed.

This is a freshly baked react project, so I didn't touch it's code, aside from the files I deleted.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: Different versions of webpack have different build outputs, that's normal, if you want to control webpack yourself, you can write your own webpack config to build your project or you can eject webpack from your React app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an issue, it's expected behavior by [`react-scripts`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/main/packages/react-scripts) because these logs are hardcoded in `react-scripts` and currently, there are no options for disabling them. You have probably had an older version of `create-react-app` in your previous laptop which might have not logged this information on the console.

What is really happening is that you are running `react-scripts` with `npm start` and `react-scripts` are logging webpack logs.

There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114824/how-can-i-make-react-scripts-build-quiet) which is similar to yours about running `react-scripts` silently.

If you really don't want to see the output you can redirect it to null:

- Linux & Mac: `npm start > /dev/null`
- Windows CMD: `npm start > null`
- Windows Powershell: `npm start > $null`